# Grails Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I have unit test wich extends GrailsUnitTestCase :

```
 import grails.test.GrailsUnitTestCase
 class HttpdParserSpec extends GrailsUnitTestCase {

 }
```

However I saw in Grails documentation that is deprecated.
I tried to use the following :

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor

@TestFor(HttpdParser)
class HttpdParserSpec {
}
```

I obtain the following error :

> Cannot add Domain class [class fr.edu.toolprod.parser.HttpdParser]. It
>   is not a Domain!

It's true.It's not a Domain class.I only want test a simple class HttpdParser.

What am I doing wrong ?

So how to make a simple unit test ? Have you an example ?

Comment: If it's just a simple unit test, don't use @TestFor, but just create a spock test without any Grails dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the TestFor annotation.  Just write a unit test as you normally would.  TestFor is useful for rigging up Grails artifacts and relevant elements of the environment for unit testing them.

```
class HttpdParserSpec extends spock.lang.Specification {
    void 'test something'() {
        when:
        def p = new HttpdParser()
        p.doSomething()

        then:
        p.someValue == 42
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It's more clear for me. So, I will look further details about Spock ...

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use the @TestMixin annotation with the GrailsUnitTestCaseMixin like this:

```
import grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.TestMixin

@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
class MyTestClass {}
```